# XML Schema. Base64binary type vs String type

Tags: xml, xsd, base64

I need to decode a Base64 string from some XML element. Is there any difference between an element defined by `type="xs:base64binary"` and an element defined by `type="xs:string"`? Some XSD developers refuse to mark encoded strings as a base64binary. If there is no difference, what is the use of `type="xs:base64binary"`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary) correctly, there is a semantic difference.

A `base64Binary` element contains arbitrary, binary data that has been encoded as base64, which makes it basically a string (or at least string-compatible).

On the other hand, strings contain printable characters, which (usually) make up words and sentences (natural language). They cannot contain arbitrary (binary) data, because certain characters aren't allowed.

You can use `base64Binary` to indicate that the decoded data is not suitable for human consumption, where as `string` is readable/printable.

Answer (score 42):

There definitely is a difference between `base64Binary` and `string` in XSD:

- **[base64Binary](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary)** represents binary data encoded in Base64.  Its [value space](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-value-space) is the set of fixed length binary octets.  Its
  lexical space is limited to `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `+`, `/`, `=`, plus
  [whitespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#NT-S).
- **[string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#string)** represents character data.  Its [value space](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-value-space) is the set of finite-length sequences of [characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#NT-Char).  Its lexical
  space is unconstrained beyond having to consist of [XML
  characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#NT-Char).

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference is in validating the XML. A random string will not pass base64Binary validation, whereas a base64Binary content will pass string validation.

If I expect base64Binary content in the XML, and dont want a random string.