# How to write Byte[] in XML in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, wso2, xsd-validation, xml-validation

JSON response is of Filename , Content:

```
{
  “Filename” : “abc.pdf”
  “Content” : “abejmkkjshkduhjkskwbkjejjkhugaib” 
}
```

where

```
Filename : String 
Content : Byte[]
```

How to write `Byte[]` in my XSD schema ?

Comment: Why have you asked 7 questions yet [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) no answers?

Comment: Dear, I Do not know how to accept the answers

Comment: It's simply.  If you click on the [***accepted***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) link in my comment, you can read how.  (Basically all you have to do is click on the gray checkmark next to the answer.  It will then turn green.)

Comment: Now that you know how, why don't you accept the answers that have helped you?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly store raw bytes in XML files, but you can encode them in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and store the encoding.  For Base64-encoded data, use [base64Binary](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary) in XSD.

Be sure that your data is actually Base64, because [`xs:base64` is not the same as `xs:string`](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418269/290085).

Comment: Thanks for the Response Can i Use in the below Format
<xs:element name="FileContent" type="xs:base64Binary" />

Comment: Yes, provided that the content in `FileContent` is encoded as Base64.

Comment: Really thanks hughes, Last doubt Should i need to Encode as Base64 ? or directly as above mentioned i can uses as base64Binary?

Comment: During Xml and XSD Validation i'm getting this error , Could you Please help me
Is Not A Valid Value For 'base64Binary
Of Element 'FileContent' Is Not Valid., Line '3', Column '2011'.

Comment: As I said, your data has to actually be encoded in Base64 format.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Mate, Did not see. Now Working.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.